# Neo4jClient node ids

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm having trouble working out how the ID work in Neo4jClient. I want my .NET model to have an identifier property, and ideally I'd like it just to use the Neo4j autoincremented id for that node.

However, no matter what case I use (`id`, `ID`, `Id`) in my model class, it always adds this as another field in Neo4j (keeping it as 0 when I create a new node). So when I view that node in the Neo4j browser, it has a `<id>` which is auto-incremented, and also my `id` field which is always 0 (unless I manually set it in my model in C#).

I want to be able to create a new .NET model class (which will initially have an uninitialised id of 0), then once I've created it with the Neo4j fluent Cypher query, it will have the ID from the newly created node's autoincremented ID.

The examples here:
https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples

Show their `User` class of having an ID like this:

```
public long Id { get; set; }
```

But in the example for creating a new User ...

```
var newUser = new User { Id = 456, Name = "Jim" };
graphClient.Cypher
    .Create("(user:User {newUser})")
    .WithParam("newUser", newUser)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I'm unsure where this `456` magic number comes from in this example, but I just want this to be the Neo4j id, which I obviously don't know until it's created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alessandro is correct, and you *shouldn't* use the Node ID certainly not as maps to internal representations. If you were to delete a node, then create another, it may well have the same ID.

Now, there are some times you *need* to get the ID, (again **not** for use as an internal identifier) - but maybe in a Path result or something, and `Neo4jClient` does allow you to get it.

**Be warned, this way dragons lie.**

`Neo4jClient` is all about POCO's, it helps you translate them to and from Neo4j, the example from the WIKI is just that, an example, the ID could have come from any number of sources, or be any type, for example, I quite often use `GUID`s for my IDs. Equally, I've used things like [SnowMaker](https://github.com/tathamoddie/SnowMaker) in the past to generate IDs. If you want the Node ID, you need to wrap your POCO in a `Node<T>` type, so:

```
client.Cypher.Match("(n:User)").Return(n => n.As<User>()).Results;
```

gets you an `IEnumerable<User>` response, whereas:

```
client.Cypher.Match("(n:User)").Return(n => n.As<Node<User>>()).Results;
```

gets you an `IEnumerable<Node<User>>` response, where each instance of `Node<T>` will have a property - `Reference` which is the Neo4j ID and another - `Data` which is the `T` / POCO bit.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good point about a new node having the same id as a deleted one. Internally, I'd be happy using a GUID, it just looks a bit messy as it will end up on a URI. Mind you, it's not ideal either than a Neo4j ID appears on a uri! I'll think of another way of referencing a specific node then. This is basically for an 'edit' page on a website/app.

Comment: If it's on Azure, snowmaker is very useful and easy for unique IDs

Comment: Thanks, will check it out. It is on Azure, but contained in Docker containers.

Answer (score 3):

using id from Neo4j is a wrong practice since it may change over time or be assigned to a different node. 
Have a look at this plugin:

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid

Cheers,

Comment: seems its discontinued. Just for ref: https://graphaware.com/framework/2021/05/06/from-graphaware-framework-to-graphaware-hume.html